# Regex to match ampersands in a URI that are followed by an equals and not another ampersand

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex knowledge is escaping me on this one...

Say I have a URL with a URI as a query parameter, ala:

```
http://hostname.com?uri=http://website.com/company/YoYo+&+Co+Inc&type=company
```

...assuming our uri param doesn't contain any params itself, I want to manually parse out the query params in Javascript, but obviously the ampersand in our embedded uri param makes it more difficult then simply splitting on all ampersands and running with it from there.

What I really want to do is define a regex that matches only question marks and ampersands that are followed by an equals prior to being followed by another ampersand (or end of line). I came up with this which comes close but is including the non-capturing text as well and I'm not sure why:

```
[?&](?:[^&]+)=
```

...that results in a match on `?uri=` as well as `&type=` which is close but capturing more than I want. What am I doing wrong such that it's not capturing just the `?` and `&` in matches? In other words, it should only be capturing the `?` prior to uri and the `&` prior to type.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like it to be matching? I don't quite understand what the goal is.

Comment: Updated to hopefully be a bit more clear...

Comment: Check out http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: If I understand correctly this should be your regex: [?&](?==)

Comment: @igasparetto that also breaks on the & contained in the uri param. I need a regex that only matches the [&?] if it's followed by an = before another &

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you just want to match the ? or & then your regex should be:

```
[?&](?==)
```

**Explanation:**

`[?&]` is a set of characters containing just ? and &. Meaning it will look for one of those.

`(?= )` This is a positive lookahead. It means "This has to come after the main match but don't include it". So to make it find an = looks kind of funny as `(?==)`

---

If you want to include the word "uri" or "type" then add a `\w` after the character set and before the lookahead:

```
[?&]\w+(?==)
```

`+` means "match 1 or more"

---

And just one more in case that's not exactly what you're looking for! If you want to get rid of the &/? but keep the text we'd wrap the character set in a positive lookBEHIND. The syntax for that is `(?<= )`. That would change the regex to this:

```
(?<=[?&])\w+(?==)
```

Example of that at work: http://regexr.com?35q0u

---

In reponse to comment:
You can match just the ? and & by putting the \w+ inside of the positive lookahead:

```
[?&](?=\w+=)
```

And because I'm bored and like regexs a bit too much, here's one that will match the value of the tag:

```
(?<==).*?(?=[&?]\w+=|$)
```

Example: http://regexr.com?35q11
There's multiple highlighted sections because global matching is on.

Comment: Because you don't have a ? or & directly followed by a =. Do you want to match the word "uri" too? In that case it'd like this: http://regexr.com?35q0r

Comment: Close...I only want to match & and ? that are followed by an = prior to an ampersand. But I only want to *capture* the & or ?, not any of the text that follows.

Comment: i.e...I can't figure out how to do the *non*-capture while still doing the match

Comment: Edited the answer to finally do what you want.. I think :P

Comment: Woot! Glad I could help. And thanks for accepting, my first accepted answer :D